# How to match alphanumeric characters in python regexp?

Tags: python, regex

I’d like to get all the words from a text, including unicode characters, not including hyphens or underscores or any other non-alphanumeric characters.

I.e. I want something like this:

```
>>> getWords('John eats apple_pie')
['John', 'eats', 'apple', 'pie']
>>> getWords(u'André eats apple-pie')
[u'André', u'eats', u'apple', u'pie']
```

With

```
getWords = lambda text: re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+').findall(text)
```

it works for the first example, but not the second, and the other way around with this:

```
getWords = lambda text: re.compile(r'\w+', re.UNICODE).findall(text)
```

Comment: Split the string by space. Easy. :)

Comment: @Tushar and `_` and `-`?

Comment: Did you post this before it was finished?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Nope, it’s finished I guess. Are you missing more information?

Comment: Ah, no; I was expecting another sentence at the end but now I see what you mean.

Comment: Hi @rumpel the duplicated post answers your problem, AFAIK. If you think it doesn't please ping me back.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `re.split(r'[ -_]', str)`

Comment: @Tushar, I want that to be generic. I.e. there a thousands of non-alphanumeric characters that I don’t want to have to list manually.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Thanks. In the duplicate are indeed some solutions that should work which use manual parsing instead of regular expressions. Too bad python’s regexps can’t deal with this.

Comment: @rumpel What makes you think, `split` is not generic, when your delimiters are fixed and text can contain any character. IMO, `split` will work on Chinese, Japanese characters.

Comment: @Tushar: I mean the delimiters aren’t fixed either. Could be some non-breaking space or – or … or ☺. So this list while fixed, would be very very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.isalnum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) instead of RegEx in this case:

```
getWords = lambda x: ''.join(i if i.isalnum() else ' ' for i in x).split()
```

Comment: Oh yeah, use `str.isalnum` instead if you don't think that digit or other stuff is a part of words.